# Why does one want to have the standard definition of localization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

The standard way of defining the localization of a commutative ring is as follows: given a multiplicatively closed subset $S\subset R$ the localization is defined first by considering the set $R\times S/\sim$ where
$$
(r,s) \sim (r',s') \text{ if there exists a } u \in S \text{ such that } u(rs' - r's) =0
$$
the rest is just equipping this set with a ring structure, but my question lies here: why do we want the $u$? Don't we not want nilpotents in our denominator?

Comment: To give an intuitive explanation of why $r/s = r'/s'$ should hold if there is such a $u$: then we would expect $\frac{r}{s} = \frac{rs'u}{ss'u} = \frac{r'su}{ss'u} = \frac{r'}{s'}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't require the existence of such an $u$, $\sim$ won't be transitive in general (and hence not an equivalence relation). This becomes quite apparent when you attempt to prove that transitivity holds.

Comment: Do you know of an example of a localization and elements which gives you a nilpotent in the $(rs' - r's)$ part?

Comment: If $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y] / (xy)$ and $S$ is the powers of $x$, then $y/1 = 0/1$ in $S^{-1} R$ even though $y\cdot 1 - 0\cdot 1 \ne 0$ in $R$.  (More generally, the definition is about taking into account zero divisors by elements of $S$, not just nilpotents.)